# Is there any way to delete the light bounces without losing the illumination?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

Is there any way to delete the light bounces without losing the illumination? I mean, can i delete or hide that 'white dot' on the image without losing the coloration made by the lighting? (I'm doing this on Blender Render)

[image]

Comment: Make the specular value less

Comment: That's only on the texture/material, right?

Comment: Right in the material settings there is a Specular setting

Comment: Hmm, i actually know about that, but is there another option besides that? (just to know) now i think ill do what you say because it's the easiest and fastest way, thanks again :)

Comment: remove specular from your lamp settings, or move it where the plane won't reflect it. Or use render passes and render with spec separated, then compositing, mask....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done by disabling the specular highlights of a lamp.

To do this, with the lamp selected and in the *Properties* panel, go to the *Object Data* tab (this is how it's actually called, but it's the one with the *Lamp* icon), and under the *Lamp* subsection uncheck the *Specular* checkmark.

[image]